# How to make observable's subscription to be called in test and how to make sure that observable's body was already executed

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have ngOnInit where I have subscription that builds form in it's body

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myObservable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe((myObservable) => {
  if (myObservable) {
    this.buildForm();
  }
});
}
```

I want to test some things in this form, but I'm not able to make body of this subscription to be executed in test. I've tried something like that:

```
it('should access subscription body and create form', fakeAsync(() => {
component.myObservable$ = of(true);
tick();
component.myForm.controls['field1'].setValue('field1');
component.myForm.controls['field2'].setValue(['field2']);
component.resetForm();
//here checks that field1 and field2 were reset
}));
```

And I get error in line #4 of test, that form doesn't contain any controls yet and I see in coverage, that body of subscription wasn't reached.
I have fixture.detectChanges in beforeEach function and I've checked that ngOnInit is really called. I've tried also to call it specifically inside test. I don't have this problem if I have Subject instead of observable, as I'm always able to reach subscription's body by calling .next(). How should I initialize this observable here?

The second question: if my first problem is solved, will tick() be enough to be sure, that form was already built in subscription's body and I can manipulate it's controls without problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tick` can you try `flush` so that the subscribe get completed? also can you remove the before each code?

**I am guessing since we do not have fakeAsync on the before Each we are getting that issue I think, that is why I moved ngOnInit to inside the it block**

```
it('should access subscription body and create form', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.myObservable$ = of(true);
    component.ngOnInit();
    flush(); // completes the subscribe!
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.myForm.controls['field1'].setValue('field1');
    component.myForm.controls['field2'].setValue(['field2']);
    component.resetForm();
    //here checks that field1 and field2 were reset
}));
```

Comment: unfortunately no. But I think I found a solution. Tick() and flush() were not working for me. I found a solution somewhere which suggested that even if I have detectChanges in beforeEach, I could try to call component.ngOnInit after myObservable = of(true); line. And it worked indeed.  I don't know why if in theory ngOnInit was already called and created subscription. I see that your solution is similar so I guess it's correct too.

Comment: @RIPI Since we do not have `fakeAsync` on the before Each we are getting that issue I think, that is why I moved `ngOnInit` to  inside the `it` block